# Gaining an intuition on a multi-variable calculus/optimisation problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Mathematics,

This is my first ever question so please let me know if I have conducted myself incorrectly in posting in this forum.

I have a question related to multivariable calculus which I have solved, as follows. Given:

$$f(M,W)=kM(1+pW)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial M}=k(1+pW), \frac{\partial f}{\partial W}=kpM$$
$$condition \frac{\partial f}{\partial M}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$$
$$k(1+pW)=kpM$$
$$M=W+ \frac{1}{p}$$

The result finds the ratio between $M, W$ that maximizes the function for each summed amount $M+W$, such that $M+W=Q$. For example:

$k=1, p=1, f(M,W) = M(1+W)$

Take $Q = 11$, arbitrarily choose $M=4, W=7$ such that $M+W=Q$

Therefore $f(4,7)=4(1+7)= 32$

Now using solution found earlier:

$M+W=11, M=W+1$ (earlier result), $\therefore M=6, W=5$.

$f(6,5) = 6(1+5) = 36$, which is greater than $f(4,7)$ and all other combinations of $M, W$ such that $M+W=11$.

Another way to state this is to say for each increment of $Q$, what amount of $M$ and $W$ combined will produce the greatest value of the function $f (M, W)$.

I have confirmed this using Microsoft Excel for values of M, W up to 100. I am unable to discern why equating the partial differentials produces this optimized result.

This condition might not even be correct to use and has been coincidentally stumbled upon; hopefully not the case but would like clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  The function you describe has no maximum (it is easy to make the value as large as you wish).  Is there possibly some constraint on $M,W$ that has to be satisfied?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, the constraint was to find a new function that follows a path such that the gradient of the original function is always maximised

Comment: What does it mean for a gradient (a vector) to be maximum?

Comment: I think you should edit your post to state your question clearly.  As it is, I'm not sure what anyone can say.

Comment: I have restated the question to include missing information and provided much-needed formatting if you would be so kind as to have another look.

Comment: If $g(M,W)=M+W$ is constrained to be constant, then we can use Lagrange multipliers to see that the condition is $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$.  This translates to the equality of the two partials, as you said.  But it does not give a ratio...you end up with two linear equations in $M,W$:  the one you wrote and the constraint $M+W=Q$.  You can then solve for $M,W$.

Comment: Thank you greatly for the in-depth reply; the missing link is indeed the Lagrange multipliers technique. I'll have to go and study on it some more as it is a topic I somewhat neglected in University.

Comment: Glad to help.  It's a very useful technique, well worth reading about.

Answer (score 1):

Your excel approach is correct, that is why you are getting the correct result. The formal approach is applying the [Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) or the [Karush Kuhn Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions. Basically is nullifying the sum of all the gradients of the objective and constraints together, including proper positive (or zero if possible) multipliers. If no constraints, you only equal the gradient to zero.

The neccesary condition is:
$$
-\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g = 0
$$

keeping the constraints $g=0$ and everything positive $M,W,\lambda \ge 0$.

Thus:
$$
\text{max} \ f(M,W)=kM(1+pW)\\
 g(M,W)=M+W-Q=0
$$

$$
-{\partial f \over \partial M}+ \lambda {\partial g \over \partial M}=-k(1+pW)+\lambda=0\\
-{\partial f \over \partial W}+ \lambda{\partial g \over \partial W}=-kpM+\lambda=0 \\
g = M+W-Q=0
$$

From here:
$$
W={\lambda \over kp}-{1 \over p}\\
M={\lambda \over kp}\\
{\lambda \over kp}+{1 \over p}+{\lambda \over kp}=Q\\
\lambda=\frac{kp}2(Q-\frac 1p)
$$

Finally:
$$
W=\frac Q2 -\frac 1{2p}\\
M=\frac Q2 +\frac 1{2p}\\
$$

For $k=1,p=1,Q=11$, $W=5,M=6$ with $f=36$

Comment: I see. let me change it

Comment: Thank you greatly for this response, very helpful indeed. For future readers, I think the second differential line $-{\partial f \over \partial M}+{\partial g \over \partial M}=-kpM+\lambda=0 \\$ should be with respect to W, not M. Other than that I could follow along very easily!

Comment: yes!... right.. somebody changed that already!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have momentarily settled for a point $(M,W)$ satisfying the condition $M+W=Q$. But you are not utterly convinced and therefore try for a nearby admissible point $(M+\delta, W-\delta)$. This nearby point would lead to
$$\eqalign{f(M+\delta, W-\delta)&=f(M,W)+ {\partial f\over\partial M}\delta+{\partial f\over\partial W}(-\delta)+o(\delta)\cr &=f(M,W)+\left({\partial f\over\partial M}-{\partial f\over\partial W}+o(1)\right)\delta\qquad(\delta\to0)\ .\cr}$$
If ${\partial f\over\partial M}-{\partial f\over\partial W}\ne0$ here you could increase $f$ in an admissible way by choosing a small $\delta\ne0$ of suitable sign.

It follows that at an optimal admissible point $(M,W)$ one necessarily has ${\partial f\over\partial M}={\partial f\over\partial W}$, as claimed in your recipe.

A general treatment of situations of this kind would lead to the method of Lagrange multiplyers.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines initially but used numbers instead of generalizing like I should have and got lucky with equating the partial differentials leading to the correct solution. Much appreciated!